# Efficient function to detect equal elements at distance k

Tags: python, list, loops

I am looking for an efficient function to find equal elements at distance k inside a list.

Input example:

```
v=['a','c','d','e','a','c','e','e','e','d']
k=4
```

Desired output:

```
['a', 'c', 'e']
```

why:
'a' is both in position 0 and 4 [4-0=k], 'c' is both in position 1 and 5 [5-1=k], 'e' is both in position 3 and 7 [7-3=k]

If it's possible, I am looking for something more efficient than looping element by element with a for loop. That is, I'm looking for something better than the following:

```
def dist_k(k, v):
    v_len = len(v)
    out = []
    for i in range(0,v_len,1):
        if i+k < v_len:
            if v[i] == v[i+k]:
                out.append(v[i])
    print(out)
```

Comment: It's not entirely obvious to me what "equal elements at distance k" means exactly…

Comment: Given `v=['a','c','d','e','a','c','e','e','a','d']` (notice one more `a`) and `k=4` should the result ìnclude two `a`s so be `[a, c, e, a]`?

Comment: Added a 'why' section to clarify. about @Mushroomator the answer is yes.

Comment: You have linear complexity, It's the most efficient way to do that...

Comment: sudden_appearance is right, the only optimization you can do is to change your range to `range(0,v_len-k)` and remove your condition `if i+k < v_len`

Comment: As @sudden_appearance says it won't get better than linear as you have to look at all `n` values within the array to get a valid result, so you're stuck with minimizing contants in your code and there is only the one `if` condition you can eliminate and that's it. I am not sure how `numpy` perfoms this kind of thing, but there might be some performance gain there. That's certainly something to test.

Comment: What about @leleogere answer? it looks really compact and with a "1-shot" comparison

Comment: I am flexible on I/O, anyway let's assume a list.

Comment: If you can have your input as a numpy array and you accept the output as a numpy array, I think my method is likely to be the fastest one. If your input is a list and/or you want the output to be a list, the other methods will likely be faster for small lists (because no conversion are needed)

Comment: @Terru_theTerror Apologies! I need my CPUs for something else at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDIT

I found a clever way to do that even faster, without the need of `np.roll`, and that will not consider the array as circular :

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v = ['a','c','d','e','a','c','e','e','e','d']
>>> v_np = np.array(v)
>>> k = 4
>>> v_init = v_np[:-k]
>>> v_init[v_init == v_np[k:]]
array(['a', 'c', 'e'])
```

The idea is I store the begining of the array without the last `k` elements (I will not need then as there are less than `k` elements after them). I store the array as I will need it twice.

```py
>>> v_init = v_np[:-k]
>>> v_init
array(['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c'])
```

Then I use the second part of the array without the first `k` elements:

```py
>>> v_np[k:]
array(['a', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'd'])
```

Then I can compare the two arrays:

```py
>>> v_init == v_np[k:]
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False, False])
```

And finally I can get the element corresponding to the index from `v_init` (not from `v` because the length of the arrays do not match):

```py
>>> v_init[v_init == v_np[k:]]
array(['a', 'c', 'e'])
```

**Performances**
As it uses numpy (which uses C for the computations), this method will be way faster with big arrays. However, due to the conversion to a numpy array, it might be slower for small lists (not even sure, try it with your problem):

```py
def list_comprehension(v, k):
    return [v[i] for i in range(len(v)-k) if v[i] == v[i+k]]

def using_numpy(v, k):
    v_np = np.array(v)
    v_init = v[:-k]
    return v_init[v_init == v[k:]]

>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> v = np.random.rand(100000).tolist()  # I consider that the input is a simple list
>>> timeit(lambda: list_comprehension(v,k), number=1000)
7.875344538999343
>>> timeit(lambda: using_numpy(v,k), number=1000)
3.646597085000394
```

### Original answer, for circular arrays

```py
import numpy as np
v = np.array(['a','c','d','e','a','c','e','e','e','d'])
k = 4
v[v == np.roll(v,-k)]
```

Basically `np.roll` shifts the array by `k` elements, then I just compare the initial array with the shifted array, and I keep elements for which they are equal :

```py
>>> np.roll(v, -k)
array(['a', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> v == np.roll(v,-k)
array([ True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
>>> v[v == np.roll(v,-k)]
array(['a', 'c', 'e'])
```

Note that this method will consider the array is circular, i.e. it considers the first and last values of the array as adjacent :

```py
>>> v=np.array(['a','c','d','e','a','c','e','e','e','d', 'a'])
>>> v[v == np.roll(v,-k)]
array(['a', 'c', 'e', 'd'])
```

Comment: Please consider adding what is `np`, as `numpy` is not a built-in module

Comment: Done! I consider it so famous that I haven't even thought to do it

Comment: Also worth mentioning that numpy is C written lib, which will act significantly faster than pure python code on big arrays

Comment: I added a speed comparison at the end

Comment: I added it, it is still faster

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
    v=['a','c','d','e','a','c','e','e','e','d']
    k=4 

    result = [v[i] for i in range(len(v)-k) if v[i] == v[i+k] ]
```

Comment: Although you just rewrote the same (almost the same) code to list comprehension, I would consider it as an improvement as list comprehension is the most efficient way in python to dynamically create a list

Comment: Good observation @sudden_appearance. The list comprehension is also more readable for someone familiar with list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is any more or less efficient than the other suggestions but it's another option:

```
v = ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'd']
k = 4
print([e for e, f in zip(v, v[k:]) if e == f])
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'c', 'e']
```